# Editing Code Colors in the Editor

Tags: overleaf

I am working in Overleaf right now and I am trying to determine if there is a way to change the colors of certain parts of the physical LaTeX code. For example, suppose I have the following code:

```latex
\subsection{Forest Age Classes}
SOME TEXT HERE
SOME TEXT HERE
SOME TEXT HERE

\begin{align}
    & J_{t} = \sum_{k=1}^{kmax} j_{t,k}  & \forall i,j,t \\
    & j_{t,k} = sj_{t-1,k-1}    & k=2,...,kmax; \quad  \forall i,j,t \\
    & j_{t,1} = dJ_{t-1} + \tilde{d}\mathcal{G}_{t-1} & \forall i,j,t
\end{align}
```

I think that it would be useful in large documents to have environments coded a different color than the text body. With a large document, I can easily find myself lost in the code because it can be hard to distinguish one section from the other if the code colors are all the same color. In the code above, it would be convenient to change the `\subsection{}` as well as the `\begin{}` and `\end{}`. Is this possible in Overleaf or other LaTeX editors?

Comment: [Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.] You can change the editor theme from the Overleaf menu options, but I'm afraid there isn't a way to customise specific parts like this—sorry!

Comment: That's unfortunate. Hopefully that type of functionality can come through in later updates! It would definitely help with making the code pop out more and have a bit more clarity.